# Is my understanding of conjugation in a group correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I'm reading some lecture notes and watching some videos, but the purpose of group conjugation was never really made explicit. After a good amount of time, this is what I've come up with, in the context of the symmetric group $S_n$.

> Every element of $S_n$ can be decomposed into disjoint cycles. There are $n!$ distinct cycle sets, as $S_n$ has cardinality $n!$. However, some cycles are equivalent to others, up to relabeling. If I have a cycle set $\sigma$ and want to obtain another equivalent cycle set, I can get any element of $S_n$, say $\tau$, and perform the following group composition $$\sigma'=\tau^{-1} \sigma \tau$$ The resulting element $\sigma'$ will have the same cycle set as $\sigma$.

If my understanding is indeed correct (if not please let me know!), I have a few questions.

1. The total number of cycle sets (equivalent ones that are relabeled are considered distinct) in $S_n$ is $n!$. If we count the equivalent ones as a single cycle set, then how many do we have left over? Is there a theorem for this? I am guessing it is some fraction of $n!$.
2. Is it safe to think of conjugation in this way? Because in other groups, there may not necessarily be a cycle set anymore. So what would conjugation by an element $g$ mean then? I understand that in an abelian group, conjugation trivially yields the exact same element. What about non-abelian groups?

Gun to head, if asked to explain conjugation of an element $h$ in $g$, in 10 words or less, my answer would be

> It generates all of the cousins of $h$.

Would this roughly capture the essence of conjugation?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449041/counting-the-number-of-elements-in-a-conjugacy-class-of-s-n and http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_formula_in_symmetric_group.

Comment: The complete answer to your question #1 is given by the group class equation, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class#Conjugacy_class_equation