# Number of conjugated to (12)(34) in $S_6$ of rank 6

Tags: group-theory

I need to find the number of conjugated to the permutation (12)(34) in the symmetric group $S_6$ of rank 6

My answer is 6! = 720

Is this correct?

I concluded that (12)(34)=(12)(34)(5)(6) and the number of combinations for $S_6$ is 6! as they need to be the same partition type

Edit:

It seems to be $6! / (2*2*1*1) = 180$

Comment: How did you obtain this answer?

Comment: $6!$ would mean that every permutation is a conjugate of this one. Do you know the criterion with cycle decomposition?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449041/counting-the-number-of-elements-in-a-conjugacy-class-of-s-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: An element of $S_6$ is conjugated with $(12)(34)$ if it has the same disjoint cycle type, that is you have to count the amount of elements that look like $(a b)(cd)$ such that $(ab)$ and $(cd)$ are disjoint transpositions.

Comment: Ok, so it is 105?

Comment: Nope. It is $45$. I will help you to count this. How many choices do you have for $(a b)$ to 'fill in' $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 2):

The number of permutations with cycle type $(2,2,1,1)$ is ${6\choose2}\cdot{4\choose2}/2=45$.  (I divided by two because there is double counting.)